# PAM unable to dlopen(pam_slurm.so): libslurm.so.35: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, slurm, hpc, pam, sshd

after installing slurm on a fresh machine and trying to restrict ssh access I receive the error:

```
Oct 12 11:29:00 localhost sshd[5087]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_slurm.so): libslurm.so.35: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 12 11:29:00 localhost sshd[5087]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_slurm.so
Oct 12 11:29:00 localhost sshd[5087]: fatal: Access denied for user test by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

libslurm.so.35 is located in /usr/local/lib, which is also added to PATH.

However, on a different server the following error arises:

```
Oct 11 19:08:12 node-cpu-02 pam_slurm[13762]: Unable to dlopen libslurm.so.35.0.0: libslurm.so.35.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 11 19:08:12 node-cpu-02 pam_slurm[13762]: access granted for user test (uid=3010)
```

but the ssh restriction works.

Did anyone experience a similar problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to rebuild the the pam module